# Why is my split method is not functioning as intended when I am splitting numbers from operator

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, split, stack

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgEvk.png)

```
public class Model {
private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

private String expression;
private String exp[];


    public Model()
    {
        expression = sc.nextLine();
        split();
    }
    
    public void split()
    {
        
        //splitting the entered expression to array of operators alone and array of the numbers then create Arraylist to combine the operators and numbers together as if it is a string expression  but as an array
        String num[]= this.expression.split("[/+/*/-]");
        String preop[]= this.expression.split("[0123456789]"); // this will give [empty, operator, operator...] therefore we will create another array to fill in the ops excluding empty
       
        
                    System.out.println("Test: Printing num Array");
                    for(int i = 0; i<num.length;i++)
                        {
                    System.out.print(num[i]+",");
                        }
                    System.out.println("\nTest: Printing preOp Array");
                    for(int i = 0; i<preop.length;i++)
                    {
                    System.out.print(preop[i]+ ",");
                    }
                
        
        
        ArrayList<String> op = new ArrayList<>();//I used arraylist because easier
        for(int i = 1; i<preop.length;i++)
        {
            op.add(preop[i]);
        }
        
                System.out.println("\nTest of the fixed preOp array: " + op);
                
                
        //putting the operands and the operators together in the same array
                
        ArrayList<String> exp = new ArrayList<>();
        //fill the arraylist with numbers then add the operators to it by using number (index of the operator +1 +count)
        for(int i = 0; i <num.length;i++)
        {
            exp.add(num[i]);
        }
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <op.size();i++)
        {
            exp.add(i+1+count, op.get(i));
            count++;
        }
        
                System.out.println("Test: " + exp);
    }
```

The problem is that the op array is giving empty slot [op, op, empty, op] whenever user inputs a double digit numbers in the expression.

I was expecting similar results when user enters one digit numbers where it gives the intended results as in the image [input with one digit numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY6nt.png)

Comment: What are the extra `/` for in the first regex? What do you think splitting on `[0123456789]` will result in? If you've split the expression on the operator(s) what do you need the additional split for? Unrelated, but if you want an expression parser, just write an expression parser--it'll be much more effective for anything but the simplest expr.

Comment: I took it from google, th extra / because it is related to a lesson I do not know yet so I just copy pasted it for the time being.  I am splitting number and operators alone then combine so i can change the entire input expression to an array in order to change from infix to postfix

Also thanks for informing about expression parser, but I am currently kind of coding what the expression parser does as a practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because this

```
this.expression.split("[0123456789]");
```

You split by a single digit, so 43 is split into 2 parts as well with an empty string in between.
Also, you don't need to name all the digits in the regex, you can just do a range `"[0-9]"`. If you want to match for 1 or more digits add a `+`. This should work:

```
this.expression.split("[0-9]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in one go using a regex to split at any of the operators and keeping them using lookahead and lookbehind:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String first  = "3+2*3-4";
    String second = "3+2-43*3";

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitExpression(first)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitExpression(second)));
}

static String[] splitExpression(String input){
    String regex = "((?<=(\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/))|(?=(\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/)))";
    return input.split(regex);
}
```

output:

```
[3, +, 2, *, 3, -, 4]
[3, +, 2, -, 43, *, 3]
```